# Can a Mosaic Dataset have rasters with different vertical units?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic-dataset

I am creating a Mosaic Dataset (ArcMap 10.3) that contains LiDAR DEMs from a number of different US states.

The data is in different coordinate systems (UTM, State Plane meters, State plane feet), different cell sizes (1m, 1.5m, 1.8m, 3.5 ft), and different image formats (Arc GRID, FGDB, IMAGINE, TIFF). Additionally where there isn't any LiDAR, I want to use the NED 1/3 arc second data instead (http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/). The NED data is stored in Geographic coordinate system and the horizontal units are in decimal degrees. I have set the coordinate system of the Mosaic dataset to a UTM zone in the middle of my study area.

Most of the DEM data is in meters, but some of the DEMs have vertical units in feet. I want the Mosaic dataset to be consistently in meters (horizontal and vertical). Should I convert the vertical units to meters before I add the data to the mosaic dataset? Or is there something I can do within the mosaic dataset like a function that can work on a subset of the rasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of the datasets you want to mosaic should be in the same spatial reference system, same cell sizes, and share the same vertical datums and units of measure to avoid introducing errors into the output.

Comment: I was able to create my Mosaic Dataset with the source rasters comprising of different cell sizes, projections, and horizontal units. I did have to convert the ones that had vertical units of feet into meters however. Perhaps this wasn't the ideal approach but it seems to be working.